# c++ Destructor de-allocation failing

Tags: c++, destructor

In the below c++ code, during destructor call, it is crashing with the below error.

If this message is printed, at least the program hasn't crashed yet!
But you may want to print other diagnostic messages too.
DSCodes(16782,0x1000efe00) malloc: *** error for object 0x10742e2f0: pointer being freed was not allocated
DSCodes(16782,0x1000efe00) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug

Can someone point me to the mistake in the destructor

```
class Pair {
 public:
  int *pa,*pb;
   Pair(int, int);
   Pair(const Pair &);
  ~Pair();
 };
 
Pair::Pair(int p1, int p2)
{
    this->pa = new int;
    this->pb = new int;
    *pa = p1;
    *pb = p2;
}
Pair::Pair(const Pair &obj)
{
    this->pa= new int;
    this->pb = new int;
    this->pa = obj.pa;
    this->pb = obj.pb;
}
 
Pair::~Pair()
{
    if(pa)
        delete (pa);
    if(pb)
        delete(pb);
}
 /* Here is a main() function you can use
  * to check your implementation of the
  * class Pair member functions.
  */
  
int main() {
  Pair p(15,16);
  Pair q(p);
  Pair *hp = new Pair(23,42);
  delete hp;
  
  std::cout << "If this message is printed,"
    << " at least the program hasn't crashed yet!\n"
    << "But you may want to print other diagnostic messages too." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please remind yourself the difference between `ptr = 0` and `*ptr = 0`

Comment: Why do you use dynamic allocation for two ints ? The pointers to the ints take at least as much space as the ints themselves, and this is wihout the overhead of memory allocation. Unless you have very good reason to use pointers, `int a, b` should be the way to go.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but this code can be written much more simply. All those `this->`s are just noise; the compiler knows what the members are. And you can initialize when you allocate. So `pa = new int(p1);`. And, really, that should be in an initializer list: `Pair::Pair(int p1, int p2 : pa(new int(p1), pb(new int(p2) {}`. And, finally, you don't need to test for a null pointer before deleting a pointer. So `Pair::~Pair() { delete pa; delete pb; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Pair::Pair(const Pair &obj) you actually copy the pointer, which is double destructed lateron. You want to copy the content of the pointer instead (see the Pair::Pair(int p1, int p2) constructor).

Comment: Thanks, Changing the copy constructor as below fixed it.Pair::Pair(const Pair &obj)
{
    this->pa= new int(*obj.pa);
    this->pb = new int(*obj.pb);
}

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your copy constructor assigns the `p1` and `p2` of another object the the current object (`q` holds the same `p1` and `p2` that `p`). So at the end of the program, `q`'s destructor and `p`'s destructor try to delete both the same pointers.

In the copy constructor, you should copy the integers instead of only copying the pointer.